# Git Push not showing in context menu

Tags: git, git-push, tortoisegit, git-commit

I am new to Git and don't know much about it. I have made changes to few files and want to push them to remote repository. I am using TortoiseGit as Git client. I have "Git Commit" option present in the context menu but there is not "Git Push" option.

What could be wrong? Am I missing some Git files?

Comment: You need to commit your changes before you can push them.

Comment: I did commit my changes. Anyhow, the files are somehow automatically pushed. Though I noticed that when I commit files the processing dialog box of TortoiseGit, which is committing the files, also has a "Push" button. Never got chance to use that button though, as I said, the files were automatically pushed.

Answer (score 0):

just drop down to the command line (msysgit in Windows)

```
 cd path/to/your/repo
 git push origin the-name-of-your-branch
```

There are a number of advantages of using git from the command line.

1. You get command history. Just up arrow to see what you did before.
2. Tab completion. Type a part of a branch name, hit tab, it will complete it for you.
3. Piping. Take the output of one command as input into another.
4. Scripting. You can make scripts for common tasks.
5. You will get more help on line. Most Git users use Git from the command line, so you will get more help this way than asking about TortoiseGit specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the answer to my question but I found another method of pushing the files. The Commit files dialog box has a "Push" button in TortoiseGit. I have not used it but I guess it is there to push files after committing them.

But still I am unable to find "Git Push" context menu item when I right-click on a file after committing it..

Answer (score 0):

In Explorer, Right click the repository folder, Choose TortoiseGit -> Push.